# Use str_pad to mutate a new column

Tags: r

I've have the following column/tibble:

```
Code
18
19
20
21
22
23
#With 200 more rows
```

I would like to create this tibble:

```
Muncode   Code
 0118      18
 0119      19
 0120      20
 0121      21
 0122      22
 0123      23
#With 200 more rows
```

I belive `mutate()` together with `str_pad` would create the desired tibble. Any ideas?

I've tried below code but it didn't work.

`mutate(Muncode(str_pad($code, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT))`

Comment: Are the `Code` always 2-digit? What if `Code` is `123`, how should it be padded?

Comment: What about `sprintf("%04.f", c(18, 142))`?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `paste0`? What's wrong with `paste0("01", code)`?

Comment: Typo? `str_pad($code, ...)` should not have a `$` in it. Concur with AllanCameron, `str_pad` is not the right tool for this need.

Comment: Typo? mutate(Muncode(...))` looks like you have a *function* named `Muncode`, but your output shows you trying to create a *column* named `Muncode`. While it's actually feasible to do that, it's not the "normal" way to `mutate` things.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
df %>% mutate(Muncode = sprintf("%04d", Code + 100L))
#  Code Muncode
#1   18    0118
#2   19    0119
#3   20    0120
#4   21    0121
#5   22    0122
#6   23    0123
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `str_pad` you'll need to beware of the arguments it takes and the order if you don't specify them:

> **string**    A character vector.

> **width**     Minimum width of padded strings.

> **side**      Side on which padding character is added (left, right or both).

> **pad**       Single padding character (default is a space).

*Ref: [Package stringr version 1.4.0 Index]*

You might as well need to tell mutate what data to use, and what column to create. I.e.:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dat <- tibble(Code = 18:23)

dat |>
  mutate(Muncode = str_pad(string = Code,
                           width = 4,
                           side = "left",
                           pad = 0))
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 2
   Code Muncode
  <int> <chr>  
1    18 0018   
2    19 0019   
3    20 0020   
4    21 0021   
5    22 0022   
6    23 0023
```

**Update:** If you want to pad with `01` and not `00` you could use `paste0` or `sprintf` as suggeseted in the comments. Or to stay within `stringr`, you could use `str_c`:

```r
dat |>
  mutate(Muncode = str_c("01", Code))
```

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 2
   Code Muncode
  <int> <chr>  
1    18 0118   
2    19 0119   
3    20 0120   
4    21 0121   
5    22 0122   
6    23 0123
```